# axios.all any call succeeds dont error

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I am making two axios calls like this

```
axios
  .all([call1(), call2()])
  .then(axios.spread(function(Resp1, Resp2) {}).catch(onError)
```

If one of the calls fails with a 500 server error, flow goes to catch block. I want it to go to then block even if one call fails and only go to catch if both fail. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. You could put a `catch` on your individual calls and just return some empty data: `call1().catch(error => [])`. This would mean that your final `catch` after the spread would never run however.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with `.all` of  axios. But you could do something else. Create a method which gets a promise as param, and executes it, and in case of failure, just  return null or whatever. This way you will be able to control the error case.

For that I recommend you read this article:
https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

More precicly subtitle `Rookie mistake #5: using side effects instead of returning`